# Interesting formal languages proof.

Tags: logic, formal-languages

I found this exercise (9.14) in chapter 9 of the book "Dynamic Logic" by Harel, Kozen and Tiuryn. I have absolutely no clue how to provide a proof for the exercise.

Prove that for any language $L$ over alphabet $\{a\}$ and any infinite regular language $\alpha$ over alphabet $\{a\}$, the concatenation language $L\alpha$ is regular.

Especially what happens when $L$ is language of all words over alphabet $\{a\}$ which lengths are of prime numbers.

Comment: Rather than make a correction in a *Comment*, fix it in the original question.  That way solvers don't waste time finding the correction.  Clear?

Comment: Thank you for the tip.

Comment: It should be obvious what you are trying to prove is false on cardinality considerations alone.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: That would be obvious if we could always recover $L$ from $L\alpha$ and $\alpha$, but that is not so.

Comment: Ah, @Henning, thank you. I didn't see the requirement that $\alpha$ be infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unfortunately not true. Take $L = \{a^p \mid \text{$p$ is an odd prime} \}$ and let $K = 1 + a(a^2)^*$. The language $K$ is infinite and regular. Moreover, since $L$ is a subset of $a(a^2)^*$, one gets 
$$
La(a^2)^* \subseteq a(a^2)^*a(a^2)^* \subseteq (a^2)^*.
$$ 
Suppose that $LK$ is regular. Then $LK \cap a(a^2)^*$ would also be regular. But 
$$
LK = L(1 + a(a^2)^*) = L + La(a^2)^*
$$ 
and hence $LK \cap a(a^2)^* = L$, which is not regular. Contradiction.

Comment: That is absolutely correct. Thank you for providing contradiction to it. I apologize for placing the incorrect question here but as I said before I took it from the book. Thanks a lot !

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, I suspect that the authors had in mind the following related result. If $K = a^r(a^n)^*$, then for every language $L$, the language $KL$ is regular.

Comment: It does not change the sense of the proof but $a(a^{2})^{*}a(a^{2})^{*}$ is not the subset of $(a^{2})^{*}$ but of $aa(a^{2})^{*}$

Comment: Yes, but $aa(a^2)*$ is a subset of $(a^2)^*$. The key point is that $(a^2)^* \cap a(a^2)^* = \emptyset$.